# Setting up bucket's name placed domain-style (bucket.s3.amazonaws.com) with Rails and Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip, buckets

Paperclip doc about url options:

> You can choose to have the bucket's name placed domain-style (bucket.s3.amazonaws.com) or path-style (s3.amazonaws.com/bucket).

How would look like the setup to actually have bucket's name placed domain-style? I can't force paperclip to generate urls like bucket.s3.amazonaws.com instead of s3.amazonaws.com/bucket.

Comment: I've also hit this issue - would be interested to know if you resolved it!

Answer (score 14):

Just set it like this:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
```

Or like this:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.merge!(
  :url => ':s3_domain_url'
)
```

Comment: I tried that. But it returns this error Paperclip::Errors::InfiniteInterpolationError The docs also makes me think that it would be the solution http://rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3. But it's not working.

Comment: You must also define the `:path` option with `:url`, because the default one includes `":url"` that causes the `Paperclip::Errors::InfiniteInterpolationError` exception. Paperclip bug automatically fixes the `:path` option for S3 storage... unless you use a :s3_*_url in the interpolation of `:url` (yes this is a bug). Use this for instance: `"/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'"`.

Comment: @JulienPortalier there's an erroneous single-quote at the end your example that threw me off for a couple hours. The correct setting is: `:path => "/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename"`

Answer (score 4):

Add `:url` and `:path` to the `Paperclip` default options in your `application.rb` or `environment.rb`

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  storage: :s3,
  s3_credentials: {
    bucket: ENV['MY_S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
    access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  },
  url: ':s3_domain_url',                                     # ADD THIS
  path: '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename' # ADD THIS
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you bucket name is DNS compatible then you can create url .s3.amazonaws.com/object....

but if it is not DNS compatible then you can not create as you want.

Thanks

Comment: Actually I can see the uploaded image if I directly access the url with bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/the-path-to-image I just can't make paperclip generate urls this way.