# Weird Amazon S3/Paperclip URL issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to use Paperclip and Amazon S3 for photo management in my Rails app, and I'm really close, but one issue: the link being created is wrong. When I right-click on a broken image I see this URL:

http://s3.amazonaws.com/anymarket/products/photos/000/000/008/medium/Screenshot_2014-07-29_at_7.53.40_PM.png?1406688226

Which doesn't work. But if I change the url to this it DOES work:

http://anymarket.s3.amazonaws.com/products/photos/000/000/008/medium/Screenshot_2014-07-29_at_7.53.40_PM.png?1406688226

Is there an easy way to change this?

Answer (score 0):

This will help:
[Setting up bucket's name placed domain-style (bucket.s3.amazonaws.com) with Rails and Paperclip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094761/setting-up-buckets-name-placed-domain-style-bucket-s3-amazonaws-com-with-rail)

---

**Paperclip**

Looking at the [docs](http://rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3), it seems you have the choice of either `:s3_domain_url` or `:s3_path_url`. For you, I'd recommend the `path` url:

```
# config/initializers/paperclip.rb
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ":s3_path_url"
```

This will set the `S3` path as required