# Paperclip won't generate S3 URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm migrating my user-uploaded files to a S3 bucket. They were successfully migrated [thanks to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20911776/migrating-from-local-paperclip-storage-to-s3), or so I think, as they are all listed in my bucket's dashboard. Then I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094761/setting-up-buckets-name-placed-domain-style-bucket-s3-amazonaws-com-with-rail), [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3) and [this](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Paperclip-with-Amazon-S3) guides to set up S3 integration. My `Gemfile` looks like this:

```
(...)
#Image upload
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-s3' # gem 'aws-sdk' won't work either
(...)
```

`config/initializers/paperclip.rb`:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = "/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename"
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name] = "sa-east-1.amazonaws.com"
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ":s3_path_url"
```

`config/environments/development.rb` and `config/environments/production.rb` both end with this configuration:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => {
      :bucket => "MY_BUCKET",
      :access_key_id => "MY_ACCESS_ID",
      :secret_access_key => "MY_SECRET"
    }
  }
```

But when I try to get my attachment URL, for example `User.find(163).avatar.url`, it yields:

```
":s3_path_url?1405653975"
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Use User.find(163).avatar.url, and if you later specify styles, you can pass that in to the url method like this: User.find(163).avatar.url(:style)

EDIT:

I would suggest then that you remove the file initializers/paperclip.rb and include the path to the config .paperclip_defaults like this:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :path => ":class/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename.:extension",
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => "MY_BUCKET",
    :access_key_id => "MY_ACCESS_ID",
    :secret_access_key => "MY_SECRET"
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I forgot to add the `.url` in the original post. Editing to clarify.

Comment: Still no success. =(

`    => "/system/avatars/163/original/stringio.txt?1405653975"`

Comment: Try adding the aws-sdk gem, in my latest project I have both gems, not sure if both are required... I'll surely have to check that

Comment: Is it storing the files locally or is it uploading the files to S3?